# Shielding against static, quasistatic and low frequency magnetic fields with opposing magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism

When an object, for example a sphere, shall be protected not against 
magnetic fields in general, only against a specific static, quasistatic or low frequency magnetic field coming from the outside, can this magnetic field be hindered from 
penetrating into the object through surrounding it with a 30 khz 
electromagnetic field (fed by a transmitter powered by a 9 v-battery staying in close proximity to the object)? Are opposing magnetic fields generated?

That there will be surplus magnetic fields, able to penetrate themselves into the object, which are not consumed as opposing and canceling magnetic fields due to lack of measuring of strenght and direction of the offending field, shall play no role, because my shielding problem is not about em interference, also not about health concerns.

Answer (score 0):

In general, magnetic fields are superposable - if you have one field, and another field, then the actual field at any point is just the sum of the two fields.

That means that a 30 kHz field will do nothing to prevent the penetration of a DC (or low frequency) field; it will just modulate the intensity at every point.

In other words, if you have a static field of 1 Gauss, and you apply an AC field of 1 Gauss p-p on top of it, then the field will vary from 0.5 Gauss to 1.5 Gauss. The mean will not change.

For moderate magnetic fields, you can get some shielding using a mu-metal sleeve. This will in essence "pull the magnetic field lines towards itself", leaving a region of lower magnetic field inside.

See for example this diagram from http://fieldp.com/myblog/2008/scaling-in-magnetic-shielding-calculations/:

[image]